# Not able to import module from another packages in python 3.6

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to import models.py file from gameplay package in player.views.py file but getting error:
 No module named **game.gameplay**

I've already tried:

```
from game.gameplay.models import Game
from ..gameplay.models import Game
```

The structure of my project is:

```
project
|
|
|--game(package)
|   |
|   |--gameplay(package)
|   |   |
|   |   |--__init__.py
|   |   |--models.py
|   |
|   |--player(package)
|   |   |
|   |   |--__init__.py
|   |   |--views.py
|   |
|   |--manage.py
|
|--venv
```

Comment: It looks like you have set a wrong `PYTHON_PATH`.

Comment: how wrong PYTHON_PATH?
If it's wrong python path, then what will be the correct path, can you please tell me?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the app in the settings?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    # if it is on the manage.py level (appname)
    'gameplay',
    # in a module (module.appname)
    'game.gameplay'
]
```

verify the name of the app (if it is on the manage.py level)

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class GameplayConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'gameplay'
```

in the case of the modules it is necessary to specify, so that python can be compiled correctly. for example (in a module)

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class GameplayConfig(AppConfig):
  name = 'game.gameplay'

  def ready(self):
    # example importing signals
    import game.gameplay.signals  # noqa
```

if it's correct, you should be able to import with (if it is on the manage.py level)

```
from gameplay.models import Game
```

(in a module)

```
from game.gameplay.models import Game
```

Comment: Are your applications at the same level as manage.py? or are inside a module. I had the same problem. If this is the case, it was resolved by specifying it in the installation 'game.gameplay'